# Observe deep nested child components with Vee-Validate v4 in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

In Vue2 / Vee-Validate 3, it was possible to do the following to validate inputs at any depth:

```
  <FormWrapper>
    <ValidationObserver ref="validation">

      <ChildComponent1>
        <ChildComponent2>
          <ValidationProvider rules="required">
            <FormInput id="first-name" />
          </ValidationProvider>
        </ChildComponent2>
      </ChildComponent1>

      <ChildComponent1>
        <ChildComponent2>
          <ValidationProvider rules="required">
            <FormInput id="last-name" />
          </ValidationProvider>
        </ChildComponent2>
      </ChildComponent1>

    </ValidationObserver>
  </FormWrapper>
```

Regardless of the depth of nesting of the ValidationProviders, the ValidationObserver high up the component tree would detect all validation events on them automatically, and you could add a watcher on "$refs.validation.flags.invalid" to detect when the entire subtree became valid/invalid. Validation rules could be declared at the child component level.

Is there a way to achieve the same in Vue3 / Vee-Validate 4?

All of the examples from the Vee-Validate v4 documentation show using **Form** and **Field** components inside the *same* component template, and additionally having to define the entire form's schema in one place (rather than setting the rules against each child component).

I've tried basically repeating the above, using **Form** in place of **ValidationObserver** and **Field** in place of **ValidationProvider**, but I cannot achieve the desired effect.

**Update**

I have since managed to achieve the desired effect in Vue3 using Vuelidate. However if anyone figures out how to do this in Vee-Validate, I'd be interested.

Comment: Unfortunately Validate currently seems to be [lacking an active maintainer](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/1163). :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, and I was struggling with some of the same issues as you are describing. I sort of got it working, please check out if this could be of any help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vee-validate-nested-child-components?file=pages/index.vue

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this as the answer since it seems to do what is required. I'm glad I didn't go down the route of Vee-Validate though in the end, it's much more complex to get it working than it was with Vuelidate, which more or less just worked out of the box as expected (provided you don't mix Options and Composition API, then it behaves weirdly)

Comment: Yep, it seems like the answer here is to use `useField` in your custom/child components and to pass it a name which matches use in your schema.